# SQL Server not opening table within using - ExecuteScalar

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

```
Public Function ExecuteScalar_Sql(ByVal ConnectionString As String, ByVal QueryString As String, Optional ByRef Parameters As List(Of Object) = Nothing) As (Result As String, Success As Boolean, Message As String)
    Dim Success As Boolean = False
    Dim Message As String = Nothing
    Dim Result As String = Nothing
    Try
        Using cn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
            Using cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(QueryString, cn)
                If Parameters IsNot Nothing Then Parameters.ForEach(Sub(param As Object)
                                                                        cmd.Parameters.Add(param.Name, param.Value)
                                                                    End Sub)
                Result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString
                Success = True
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Message = ex.Message
    Finally

    End Try
    Return (Result, Success, Message)
End Function
```

I get this error:

> 'ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed

However I can use similar code for `ExecuteNonQuery` and it works.

If remove from within the `Using` I can get to work, just curious why it doesn't work within `Using`.

Comment: The message is clear. This code cannot work if you don't open the connection. You need a _cn.Open_ before calling the ExecuteScalar.

Comment: I am curious to see the code that works with ExecuteNonQuery without opening the connection.

Comment: AFAIK, only the `SqlDataAdapter` will automatically open a connection, if you call  `.Fill()` on it. The `ExecuteNonQuery` works just the same as `ExecuteScalar`, in my opinion and experience.

Comment: This code is very fragile and certainly not self documenting. The .Add method expects a parameter name and the parameter DataType. You should get a warning with what you are attempting that you are providing a parameter that is obsolete.

Comment: It is very good to separate your data access code from your user interface code but if you force sql statements, parameter types and connection strings to be written in the user interface then you have defeated your purpose.

Comment: My bad, I was unable to use  ExecuteNonQuery from within Using, sorry for the confusion. @marc_s thanks for the insight as document identifies same.